# Query on dataPicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Suppose my business hours are from 7am to 7pm, then default selection of time date is :
A) During business hours, a hour later than current time
B) After business hour, 7 am the next business day.

How will you calculate value for Minimum and maximum date ??

Sol -A)

```
NSDate *minDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 *1];
NSDate *maxDate = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 * 2];
```

Is above solution for (A) is correct ?? is there any other way
Can anyone provide solution for (B) ??

Please provide proper programming code in objective C with explanation ??

Comment: I'd recommend to use `NSDateComponents` which should take care of `Daylight saving time`.

Comment: can you please provide code for both queries